# Missing Entity Framework Include(lambda) extension

Tags: .net, entity-framework, lambda

The EF `OjbectSet.Include(a => a.parent)` extension is unavailable. I know I could add code to mimic it, but according to [EntityFramework 4 upgraded to 5, lambda is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518149/entityframework-4-upgraded-to-5-lambda-is-not-available) it should be available. I have the `using System.Data.Entity`, and am upgraded to EF 5 in my main project.

Looking the metadata in Assembly System.Data.Entity.dll, v4.0.0.0 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Entity.dll)

```
...

public ObjectQuery<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord> GroupBy(string keys, string projection, params ObjectParameter[] parameters);
public ObjectQuery<T> Include(string path);
public ObjectQuery<T> Intersect(ObjectQuery<T> query);
```

There is no declaration for the lambda variant of Include here. I've checked and the file version is 4.0.30319.17929, as per [Database first generation Entity Framework 5 System.Data.Entity vs EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208102/database-first-generation-entity-framework-5-system-data-entity-vs-entityframewo) . The project is generating a 4.5 assembly.

In case it's relevant, EntityFramework itself is not referenced in this assembly. It just has some data services, so it does include references to System.Data.Entity and the main data layer project.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have `using System.Data.Entity` at the top of your code file?

Comment: Yup. I'll make that clearer in my comments above. Thanks Khan.

Comment: If you have a similar project loaded, can you tell me what metadata you see for "Include"?

Comment: ReSharper does not automatically recognize that you need using System.Data.Entity when building a lambda include, it must be manually added or added by some other process.

Comment: JabberwockyDecompiler - you saved the day there for me. again, trusutng resharper too much, didn't even think i needed a ref to `using System.Data.Entity`. turned out i sure did!! thanks again - +1 for your comment

Answer (score 148, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), the method is defined in the `EntityFramework` assembly. (in EntityFramework.dll)

You'll need to add a reference to the *EntityFramework.dll* DLL as well.

Afterwards, you'll need to make sure you're referencing the namespace:

`using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Oh, blarg. :) Thank you. I suppose it moved during an upgrade.

Comment: +1, this did not answer my issue, but the comments regarding adding a reference to `using System.Data.Entity` did!!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there are different EntityFramework DLLs available.  I searched in References and added the only one I could find, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework (which didn't work).  I eventually discovered that I needed to install the .NET EntityFramework NuGet package.